# Magento 2 - How to get product attribute options value

Tags: php

I am trying to get product attribute options. Please anyone know, show me step by step. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Block/Controller/Helper..., create a constructor and inject `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface` class. For example :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $_productAttributeRepository
 */
protected $_productAttributeRepository;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $productAttributeRepository
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface $productAttributeRepository)
{
    $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
}
```

Then, in your method :

```
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface[] $manufacturerOptions */
$manufacturerOptions = $this->_productAttributeRepository->get('manufacturer')->getOptions();
You can now get options values and labels this way :

foreach ($manufacturerOptions as $manufacturerOption) {
    $manufacturerOption->getValue();  // Value
    $manufacturerOption->getLabel();  // Label
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` class in constructor like this:

```
use Magento\Eav|Model\Config; 

class class_name {

   protected $eavConfig;

   public function __construc(
       ...
       Config $eavConvig
       ...
   ){
       ...
       $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
       ...
    }
}
```

Then you can add that in your class

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

Here attribute code is **color**

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```